# Angular2 Router - loadChildren from URL

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I am using Angular CLI and would like to consume an externally developed Angular module.

Is it possible I can load a bundle file from a URL?

I have tried..

```
 {
        path: 'external', loadChildren: () =>
            System.import(`https://xxxee/bundle.js`)

    }
```

but Webpack is unable to resolve it

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: whether that module is referred in app.modules ?..

Comment: Any progress on this? As far as I can tell, this is still tough to do